Cable replacement - Identification and name of this cable
I need replace this cable but I cannot identify it. It is the same connector on both end and it is 1cm wide.
It might be LEMO or XLR but not sure.


I also found "FGG To FGG Male Plug Cable" (see pictures below). So it could be a male plug cable 1B 7 Pin. However, my cable is 1cm wide and not 9mm as mentioned in the last picture.

Thank you

That is definitely not an XLR connector.

It looks like a Lemo-compatible but not Lemo connector.
There are a number of companies in China making connectors that are compatible with the eye-wateringly expensive Lemo ones, but I suspect Lemo has IP protection on the 'styling' (rather than function) of the specific knurl they use so some alter it in various ways to distinguish their product. For example, ODU:


In addition to the other answer NorComp also have the 821B SeriesCircular Push-Pull Connectors | 1B which might be compatible:

821B007-173LYY1 is the 7 contact cable mounted plug. The datasheet has some dimensions, but only gives the diameter of the knurl so not entirely sure if compatible with the connection in the question:


Sphero is in the right of it: clone of an ODU push-pull connector.
If I'm remembering my Lemo part numbering, the part number for a likely-compatible plug would be:
FGG.1T.307.CLAC##
Where ## is the diameter of the cable collet from the range of available sizes. I would take a look at the catalog and verify dimensions. Just don't get the CYYC version unless you want to spend a few hundred on the crimper. Cable jacket dimensions and individual wire conductor/insulator thicknesses and preparation are all very important so make sure you have measured correctly. You may even need to change cables if you can't find a connector that works with it (lead times are usually horrendous). I recommend getting some metric tappet wrenches for assembly.
There are ODU connectors as well that are intermateable (unsurprisingly you will never get a rep at either company to give you a straight answer), but I've found ODU to be difficult to source in the USA. I have seen a few cases of the shells being compatible but the pins are too short to make contact with the sockets, just a heads up.

ODU Mini-snap L size 0.
Look for the specific part number here:
https://odu-connectors.com/fileadmin/media_usa/technical-documentation/downloads/catalogs/odu-mini-snap-l-series-catalog.pdf
(Found with my Identiconn).
